# How to do substitution in the selected part of a line instead of the whole line?

Tags: substitute, visual-mode

I want to do substitution in a partial of a line.
But when I type `:'<,'>s/xx/yy/g`, it always do it in the whole line.
How can I tell vim to do it in the exact selection area??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\%V` to your search. From [`:h /\%V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%V):

```
                        */\%V*
\%V Match inside the Visual area.  When Visual mode has already been
    stopped match in the area that |gv| would reselect.
    This is a |/zero-width| match.  To make sure the whole pattern is
    inside the Visual area put it at the start and end of the pattern,
    e.g.: >
        /\%Vfoo.*bar\%V
<   Only works for the current buffer.
```

So you want to do `:'<,'>s/\%Vxx/yy/g`

Comment: actually you want more something like `:s/\%Vx\%Vx/yy/g`